# Is "screw up the system" formal enough? / screw up vs. f... up

Tags: political-correctness

I am (trying to) write documentation for an online project.
I want to write a comment that is similar to:

"# ToDo: This part of the code should be hidden in a module so users can not inadvertently screw up the system"

Is "screw up the system" OK to put there?
I am not a native speaker, and "screw up" sounds to me like "f.. up"... However, I see it being used by newspapers, etc. where "f... up" would definitely have been inappropriate...

I wanted to ask what would be a good alternative as well, but [alternate-word-phrase-for-screw-up-f-up-mess-up](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69884/alternate-word-phrase-for-screw-up-f-up-mess-up), though downvoted, seems to cover that part.

Comment: Whether something is formal *enough* is entirely subjective. In my opinion "screw up the system" is fine in comments in code, but if in doubt you can say "mess up" instead.

Comment: It's not taboo, like your courser suggestion. But it's far from formal, and would be inappropriate in academic writing. 'Compromise' is appropriately formal for such contexts.

Comment: In BE, to screw up something is very informal and usually restricted to spoken English. You would need to say something like *"so users can not inadvertently **damage** the system".*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Screw up* has a colloquial but acceptable feel to it. In my scientific experience it is not offensive but does not qualify as formal technical usage. You might try *corrupt* as a correct and more formal term.